# Correct syntax to changing state with a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

I would like some help changing my state with a form

Im trying to add to this state:

```
   this.state = {
      inputs: [
        {
          inputLabel: 'label',
          inputType: 'text',
          inputValue: 'value'
        },
        {
          inputLabel: 'label',
          inputType: 'text',
          inputValue: 'value'
        }
      ],
      tempInput: {
        inputLabel: '',
        inputType: '',
        inputValue: ''
      }
    };
```

a value to the tempInput so I could set state and add it, but I don't know how to write that, it goes something like this:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [tempInput.[e.target.name]]: e.target.value });
  }
```

this is my form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Label:
          <input
            name="inputLabel"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChangeIng}
          />
```

how do I get my handleChange function to change the inputLabel string, I cant do tempInput.inputLabel because I have 3 more strings to change and I want to access it with e.target.name but I cant reach the string. thanks in advance!

p.s this is my handleSubmit if anyone doesnt understand what im trying to do:

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.tempInput];
    this.setState({ inputs, tempInput: '' });
  }
```

this is my entire code:

```
class FormG extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputs: [
        {
          inputLabel: 'label',
          inputType: 'text',
          inputValue: 'value'
        },
        {
          inputLabel: 'label',
          inputType: 'text',
          inputValue: 'value'
        }
      ],
      tempInput: {
        inputLabel: '',
        inputType: '',
        inputValue: ''
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.tempInput];
    this.setState({ inputs, tempInput: '' });
  }

  render() {
    const inputs = this.state.inputs.map((r, index) => (
      <div>
        {r.inputLabel}{' '}
        <input type={r.inputType} value={r.inputValue} label={r.inputLabel} />
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Label:
          <input
            name="inputLabel"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChangeIng}
          />
          Type:
          <input name="inputType" type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeIng} />
          Value
          <input
            name="inputValue"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChangeIng}
          />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <h1> The form : </h1>
        <div className="form">{inputs}</div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to update `label` and `type` properties? Also, your input's name is `inputLabel`. So, `[e.arget.name]: e.target.value` updates `inputLabel` property as the input's value.

Comment: yes Im sorry I forgot to mention I have more code thats exactly like the value, I just need to figure out how to do one of them and the rest will follow.

Comment: If you provide all the code we can suggest better solutions maybe :) Updating one property is simple :)

Comment: I added the entire code at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this works for your situation. Some parts are needed to be improved of course.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputs: [
      {
        inputLabel: "label",
        inputType: "text",
        inputValue: "value",
      },
      {
        inputLabel: "label2",
        inputType: "text2",
        inputValue: "value2",
      },
    ],
    tempInput: {
      inputLabel: "",
      inputType: "",
      inputValue: "",
    },
  };

  handleChange = ( e ) => {
    // Destructuring the variables from e.target.
    // This is same as
    // const name = e.target.name;
    // const value = e.target.value;
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    // Using a callback for setState since we are using the current state
    // here. If we use the current state in our setState, then it is better
    // to use a callback like below since setState is async.
    this.setState( currentState => ( {
      
      // We are spreading tempInput in a new object, then update
      // the related name properry. So while updating one property,
      // we do not erase other ones.
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [ name ]: value },
    } ) );
  }

  handleSubmit = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = [ ...this.state.inputs, this.state.tempInput ];
    this.setState( { inputs, tempInput: "" } );
  }

  render() {
    const inputs = this.state.inputs.map( ( r, i ) => (
      <div key={i}>
        {r.inputLabel}{" "}
        <input type={r.inputType} value={r.inputValue} label={r.inputLabel} />
      </div>
    ) );
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            Label:
          <input
            name="inputLabel"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
            Type:
          <input name="inputType" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            Value
          <input
            name="inputValue"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <h1> The form : </h1>
        <div className="form">{inputs}</div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AlexAlex, I've updated the answer as exactly with your code. It works if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I forgot to say, you have a `handleChange` method but you are using `handleChangeIng` in the inputs. So I've changed this also.

Comment: could you explain to me what you did here? handleChange = e => { const { name, value } = e.target; this.setState(currentState => ({ tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [name]: value } }));

Comment: I've added some explanations in the code as comments. If anything is missing do not hesitate asking again :)

Comment: I'm just having a hard time understanding why your code works and my code did not : handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

Comment: Because, if you use it like that you are updating your whole state. Like this: `this.setState( {  inputLabel: "Some label"  } )`. This is not what you want. You want to update `tempInput` state's properties. My code shows this is how we do it.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. How about:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        [prevState.tempInput[e.target.name]]: e.target.value 
    }));
}
```

Comment: thank you! I actualy tried that and I got this error:   Line 30:  'tempInput' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: hi thanks again! but I still get this error: Syntax error: C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Wix/client/src/FormG.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (31:44)
 why do we need prev state btw?

Comment: `tempInput` is part of your state. `this.setState` doesn't happen immediately so if you tried to just do `this.state.tempInput` you might have not gotten the latest state. Instead we can pass an arrow function which receives the previous state before returning the new one and do our updates depending on that.

Comment: @AlexAlex Try it again, a small parenthesis was missing

Comment: hi it doesn't work, it runs but wont change the value, check the answer up top , it works for me, thank you very much anyway!